# Pycharm flask project reload wont work

Tags: flask, pycharm

I have been using pycharm for some months, but sometimes run project button wont work as expected. Usually I click run and then I can reload the project with the same button, now instead it creates one more instances.
[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMVjb.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by going to edit configurations and changed it to single instances only.

Answer (score 0):

use the terminal
cd folderName  into your folder and try python app.py